# Holding Images to a specific Position even when window resize

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I made a website which is working fine (http://hltvnewsgenerator.com/previewavatar/) however when I change the resolution of the window myself, It moves image to some undesired position.

**I want to know how can I bind image to a specific position even when the window is getting resized.**

My code:

HTML:

```
<img :src="image" id="steamprofile">
```

CSS:

```
#steamprofile {
width: 166px; 
height: 166px; 
position: absolute; 
z-index: 1; 
left: 487px; 
top: 463px;
}
```

Comment: This is caused by improper HTML structure. your whole website's DOM is flat.. you need nesting tags to be able to control layout.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is my solution, paste this into you HTML, you gotta put css externally by yourselt.

```
<div style="position: relative">
<img src="steamProfile.png" alt="img">
<img src="https://bananagaming.tv/images/bananagaming_logo.png" id="steamprofile" style=" left: 110px; top: 23px; "></div>
```

Comment: Do I have to make these div's for every image?

Comment: @AviThour yep. I just make one example do it the same with other couple imgs to get your desired look

Comment: @AviThour Copy and paste the code above into your code and check. Do not forget the closed div tag, tell me if it works

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you use `position: absolute` and then specify exactly where the bananas are supposed to be position. This will of course break the design for all other resolutions than the one you are testing for.

You could wrap the images inside a div (or any other element), this way the absolute positioning will be relative to that div (the div that is wrapping the img). What I would do is to put the background image as a background image for a wrapping div, then put the banana image inside that div and keep the absolute positoning:

```css
div {
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/2Kjvf6f/steam-Profile.png);
  width: 977px;
  height: 226px;
}

div > img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 487px;
  width: 166px;
  height: 166px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://bananagaming.tv/images/bananagaming_logo.png">
<div>
```

Comment: Yes, you're right it is hard to understand if you don't understand :P I try as hard as I can to write simple code, if it doesn't help OP maybe it can help someone else!

Comment: personally I would just ignore the text and go straight for the code, you do you man and I do me ;)